# Поиск минимального элемента в дереве

Tags: дерево, c, бинарное-дерево, алгоритм, c++

Задача звучит так. Есть бинарное дерево поиска. Необходимо найти его минимальный элемент. Я решил задачу так:

```
int MinValue(BinaryTreeNode * node)
{
    if ( node == NULL)
        return -1;

    int right = MinValue(node->rightChild);
    int left = MinValue(node->leftChild);

    if (node->value > left)
        if (node->value > right)
            return node->value;
        else
            return right;
    else if(left > right)
        return left;
    else 
        return right;
}
```

Но мне сказали, что это не оптимальное решение. Подскажите, что не так и за счет чего можно оптимизировать поиск?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Так как в бинарном дереве поиска для каждого узла справедливо, что left < right, то соответственно для нахождения наименьшенго элемента надо топать от корня по левым веткам до упора - там и будет наименьший.

Answer (score 6):

```
int MinValue(BinaryTreeNode * node)
{
    if (node->leftChild != NULL) {
        return MinValue(node->leftChild);
    } else {
        return node->value;
    }
}
```